# Post / Put methods will not work with React and Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have my frontend with React and my backend on Spring Boot / MySQL.

The backend works and I did test the Post and Put methods on Postman. So it seems to be a front end problem. The method Get and Delete works on the React. I can LOAD and DELETE everything on my frontend.

The method I'm trying to use to do the Put / Post:

```
const baseUrl = '/api/products'

const initialState = {
    produit: {id: '', nom: '', prix: '', rabais: ''},
    list: []
}

const config = {mode: 'cors', 
credentials: 'same-origin', 
headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }}

async save() {
        const {produit} = this.state
        const requestOptions = {
            method: (produit.id) ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(produit),
            ...config
        }
        fetch(baseUrl, requestOptions);

      }
```

I've tried to change the mode and the credentials on "config". The state seems to work since I can print the variables.

I have the "proxy": "http://localhost:8080" on my package.json.

When I'm trying to do the POST / PUT method I have the following error on Chrome console:

POST http://localhost:3000/api/products 400 (Bad Request)

PUT http://localhost:3000/api/products 400 (Bad Request)

In theory the "http://localhost:3000" is the frontend, and I don't have the /api/products folder on my forntend. When I do the DELETE / GET I have the same prefix "http://localhost:3000" when I see on Chrome console, but it works.

### Edit

I'm putting the code on the Controller for Put / Post. I've tried the commented code too.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/products")
public class ProductController {
    
    //Injection de dependence
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    
//  @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
//  public @ResponseBody Product newProduct(@Valid Product product){
//      productRepository.save(product);
//      return product;
//  }
    
    @PostMapping
    public @ResponseBody Product postProduct(@Valid Product product){
        productRepository.save(product);
        return product;
    }
    
    @PutMapping
    public Product putProduct(@Valid Product product) {
        productRepository.save(product);
        return product;
    }
```

And the model:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @NotBlank
    private String nom;
    
    //Java validation
    @Min(0)
    private double prix;
    
    @Min(0)
    @Max(1)
    private double rabais;
    
    public Product() {
        
    }
    
    public Product(String nom, double prix, double rabais) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.rabais = rabais;
    }
```

How can I find out the cause of this?

Comment: Could you also put the service code with annotations?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I did it.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted an answer on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space)*.

I did it. The Java annotation `@RequestBody` was missing on the controller.